# Oracle SQL update swap numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table Oracle SQL Developer, there was a mistake somewhere in some code, and two values got flipped when the records were created.  So, what I need is something to flip all the 5's and 6's.

```
ID  Name  Type
0   Joe   5
1   Chris 6
2   Jane  5
3   Tyler 6
```

Needs to be

```
ID  Name  Type
0   Joe   6
1   Chris 5
2   Jane  6
3   Tyler 5
```

Comment: What is the datatype of "type"?  Is it a foreign key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table set Type = 11 - Type
where Type in (5,6)
```

Comment: Your solution is an awesome catch!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, thanks for the help

```
update person
set type = (decode(type, 5, 6, 6, 5))
where id in
(select id
from (select *
from persons
natural join permit_persons
natural join permits
where permit_type = 1
and type in (5, 6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more general approach. I really love tricks like `Type = 11 - Type` but sadly we work in a world where a lot of our coworkers wouldn't understand that if it's not just a one-off update.

```
update table
set Type = case when Type = 5 then 6 when 6 then 5 end
where Type in (5,6)
```